# Can imap resource returned by imap_open be serialized

Tags: php, serialization, imap

Can imap resource returned by imap_open be serialized?

I get an error "expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given" when unserialize.

Comment: Nope, this can't be serialized. It's in the manual somewhere: serialize() can't serialize connection resources. It wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As per the [documentation](http://php.net/serialize): "serialize() handles all types, except the resource-type."

Think about it. serialize can only handle what's physically stored within the PHP process. All the server-side state, login data, etc... is lost when the connection is closed. Even if the client-side data is serialized, the server will forget the connection existed, and upon un-serializing, the client'll go "hey buddy, remember me?" and the server will go "no".